# How to import three.js/some-other node package/lib/module in web-worker.ts file in angular application?

Tags: angular, web-worker

Web worker has this in first line (as it got generated when I've added with ng generate web-worker app)
///   (First line in web-wroker.ts file)

Tried adding threejs import like this
///    and also like import * as THREE from 'three';
both ways didn't work in angular application.

How to import any node lib/package in web-worker file in angular application(in my case app.worker.ts is a web-worker file)

I'm using angular 16 version and node 18 version